# What are the practical industry applications of Apache Hive?

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, hiveql, data-warehouse

I've been researching about [**Apache Hive**](https://hive.apache.org/) for the past month and all I've managed to find are articles stating what is actually Hive (by Apache), how to install it, and how to create tables in it.

I've never once found anything stating its actual practical use in the industry, even in a small brand company. 
Is Hive really not that popular in the industry compared to other data warehouses/databases?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hive is a first "SQL on Hadoop" framework that translates your SQL queries to Map-Reduce jobs.

It's more meant for batch type of processing and not interactive response time. (I would leave more Hive on Spark, Hive on Tez etc outside of this discussion )

We use Hive (along with Spark) for in ELT pipelines to ingest and transform our raw datasets into "Data Vaults" and then further to Data Marts in our Hadoop environments. We pretty much standardized on Parquet for those tables.

For BI dashboards, those Data Marts are being queried by Impala. Some other production jobs use Spark SQL. Both Impala and Spark SQL are another "SQL on Hadoop" dialects (just like Hive) that can be used to access "big data"/hadoop data sets.

That being said, we still use more traditional data warehouses (using Oracle in our case) in the same projects, but we can only push subset of data there (because of size/performance limitations of these traditional approaches).

To your question "even in a small brand company" - I think if a key word is "small" here, then you don't necessarily need Hive (and maybe any other "big data" technologies). If datasets are small and don't necessarily warrant more scalable Big Data technologies, then you should be fine and maybe even more productive in your development efforts with more traditional databases.

Answer (score 0):

We use Hive on Tez along with other tools like Spark, sqoop, etc for ETL to build data marts in a 15Pb warehouse.

I have never been able to join 50 billion rows of data in single query on some database but Hive. Hive is scalable virtually unlimited.